# Create Folder based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, create-directory

I made below code to create multiple folder based on cell value but i want that path should also picked from the cell.

I have folder path in F4. so instead of folder path i want to add F4 in code. please help

```
Sub AFolderVBA2() 'Excel VBA to make a folder.
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 4
        MkDir "Desktop:\ABC" & Range("AE" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub AFolderVBA2() 'Excel VBA to make a folder.
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Path as string

    Path = Range("F4").Value
    For i = 2 To 4    
        MkDir Path & Range("AE" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: An improvement on your (approved) answer is to check that the backslash "\" is added to the path as the last character. And an error routine to ignore when that folder already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Sub Create_Folder()

Dim Rowno As Integer
Rowno = ActiveCell.Row
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim Folder As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Path = ws.Range("AZ" & Rowno).Value
Folder = ws.Range("A" & Rowno).Value & " - " & "Docs" & " - " & ws.Range("M" & Rowno).Value
MkDir Path & Folder


End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, the Path is located in an excel column "AZ" and the row number is determined by cursor location.

Comment: This code does not answer the question, as is. And the last line of it (`MkDir Path & Folder`) is duplicating the path. Please review and edit it.